# Declaration of class as static and non static

Tags: c#, static, non-static

This is my class:

```
 public  class TestClass
 {
    public static int one;
 }
```

What's the difference between declaring it as this:

```
public static TestClass test;
```

and this:

```
public TestClass test;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find answer [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3(v=vs.80).aspx)

> A static method, field, property, or event is callable on a class even
>   when no instance of the class has been created. If any instances of
>   the class are created, they cannot be used to access the static
>   member. Only one copy of static fields and events exists, and static
>   methods and properties can only access static fields and static
>   events. Static members are often used to represent data or
>   calculations that do not change in response to object state; for
>   instance, a math library might contain static methods for calculating
>   sine and cosine. Static class members are declared using the static
>   keyword before the return type of the member, for example:
>
> ```
> public class Automobile {
>     public static int NumberOfWheels = 4;
>     public static int SizeOfGasTank
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return 15;
>         }
>     }
>     public static void Drive() { }
>     public static event EventType RunOutOfGas;
>
>     //other non-static fields and properties... }
> ```